# Beginner Swift UI multiple choice quiz

Tags: swiftui

I am a Computer Science teacher who has just taken over a department. One of the students is using Swift to develop a multiple choice quiz app and I have no idea how to use Swift so am seeking some help.

I have created the following two files but when the question number updates in the brainQuiz instance of the QuizBrain file it is not updating the ControlView i.e. showing the next question in the data structure.

Any help would be great!

This is ContentView

```
import SwiftUI

var brainQuiz = QuizBrain()

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            //Getting the question text from the data structure in QuizBrain
            Text(brainQuiz.questions[brainQuiz.numQuestion].text)
            
            //Getting the question text from the data structure in QuizBrain
            Image(brainQuiz.questions[brainQuiz.numQuestion].imageName)
            
            Spacer()
            
            VStack {
                
                ForEach (brainQuiz.questions[brainQuiz.numQuestion].ans, id: \.self) {
                    
                    title in Button(action : {
                        brainQuiz.checkAns(userAnswer: title)
                    })
                    {
                        Text(title)
                            .font(.title2)
                            .padding()
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .background(Color.blue)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                    }
                }
                
            }//vstack
            .padding()
            
        }//vstack
    }//View
}//struct

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

//This is QuizBrain.swift file

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct QuizBrain {

  let questions = [
    Question(
      text: "What is the capital of the UK?", ans: ["London", "Paris", "Berlin", "Madrid"],
      imageName: "britain"),
    Question(
      text: "What is the capital of France?", ans: ["Paris", "London", "Berlin", "Madrid"],
      imageName: "france"),
    Question(
      text: "What is the capital of Spain?", ans: ["Madrid", "Paris", "Berlin", "London"],
      imageName: "spain"),
    Question(
      text: "What is the capital of Germany?", ans: ["Berlin", "Paris", "London", "Madrid"],
      imageName: "germany"),
  ]

  var numQuestion = 0
  var score = 0

  mutating func checkAns(userAnswer: String) {
    if userAnswer == questions[numQuestion].ans[0] {
      score += 1
      print("Correct")
    }

    //If there are still questions...
    if numQuestion + 1 <= questions.count {
      numQuestion += 1  //changing the number here is not affecting the output on the screen
      print(numQuestion)

    } else {
      //quizcompleted = true
      numQuestion = 0
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SwiftUI is similar to React. The View's body is reevaluated when-ever any of the dependencies change.

What you're missing is telling `ContextView` that quizbrain is a dependency and any change to it should trigger a redraw.

The easiest way to do this is to move the global variable into a `@State` variable in the view:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

  @State var brainQuiz = QuizBrain() 

  var body: some View {  
    // ...
  }
}
```

The [`@State`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state) annotation means that `ContentView` owns `brainQuiz` and any time it changes the view should be redrawn